Is metaphysical idealism compatible with Catholicism?
Is metaphysical idealism (matter doesn't exist) compatible with Catholicism?  I'm guessing the answer is no, but I'm not sure because I think that "matter doesn't exist" is kind of a meaningless statement and everyone would agree that mind is prior to matter.  Obviously nobody is denying that matter exists in some sense, so it's hard to see what this actually means because there's nothing to compare it to.  You can't say matter exists or doesn't exist in the same way that X exists.

To deny the existence of matter is to deny the principle of individuation:
Thomistic Thesis #11:

Matter as subjected to quantity is the principle of individuation or numerical distinction—impossible among pure spirits—whereby individuals of the same species are distinct from each other.

In other words, monism would follow; there would only be one being, which is a heresy. Individual moral responsibility would also be destroyed, also a heresy. Denying that Peter and Paul are distinct individuals, for example, would lead to numerous other errors and heresies, such as that they would have the same soul (whereas the soul is the substantial form of the body, as the Council of Vienne defined).
Pope St. Pius X, Pascendi §45 (quoted here), condemned Kantianism/idealism, the philosophical basis of Modernism:

let Professors remember that they cannot set St. Thomas aside, especially in metaphysical questions, without grave detriment.


I'm not sure if all of these things follow because idealism still says that matter exists, it's just something in our stream of consciousness.  That's why I'm not sure what the difference between idealism and dualism actually is.  Also I think he was talking about a different definition of idealism which is that our minds are cut off from external reality, which actually wasn't what Berkeley was saying since for him there was nothing to be cut off from.

@wmasse Cartesian dualism is likewise condemned. A human is a body+soul composite, not a soul trapped in and disconnected from his body (angelism).

Yes. Psychological dualism is condemned. But what about metaphysical idealism (more precisely called phenomenalism) the notion that matter only exists in mind?

@wmasse We "receive our knowledge from sensible things" (Thesis 19), and "Intellectuality necessarily follows immateriality, and in such a manner that the degree of intellectuality is in proportion to the remoteness from matter" (Thesis 18). Matter is something with potentiality; beings of reason (ens rationis), like our concepts of matter, are immaterial (not matter). Thus, matter doesn't exist in our mind.

@wmasse you say in your question that matter doesn't exist is part of the definition of idealism, but say here that matter does exist in idealism. The term itself is less important than the semantic weight. You should work out a proper definition in your question, so that answers can speak to whether the thing described is reconcilable with Catholic thought and with Catholic dogma, and a good answer would seem to treat of both individually (whether it is properly called idealism by mainstream academic philosophy today or not being a secondary concern).
